# Laravel 5 / Forge and nginx, trying to set site-wide HTTPS

Tags: nginx, https

I'm having issues getting nginx to rewrite http:// traffic to https://. I'm getting a nginx 404 error page on any http:// traffic.

I'm new to nginx, but I believe I should be editing the 'default' file under the sites-available folder?

**On further inspection, it looks like the 404 is loading from the catch-all file**

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
listen 443 default ssl;

server_name default;
root /home/forge/default/public;

# FORGE SSL (DO NOT REMOVE!)
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/default/12979/server.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/default/12979/server.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
if ($ssl_protocol = "") {
    rewrite ^       https://oakjar.com/$request_uri? permanent;
}

index index.html index.htm index.php;

charset utf-8;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
}

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

access_log off;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/default-error.log error;

error_page 404 /index.php;

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location ~ /\.ht {
    deny all;
}
```

Comment: Don't edit the `default` file; create a new file for your vhost configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new file for your vhost.

Create 2 server block - 1 block to handle port 80 to redirect to 443, and 1 block for your usual configurations under port 443.

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  _;
    return       301 http://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen       443;
    server_name  _;

    # the usual ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: I had a combination of errors, port 443 wasn't open, etc. But in the end, this was the correct answer. I ended up deleting the 'default' vhost and creating a whole new domain through Laravel Forge. -Thanks